# NoClassDefFoundError caused by Kotlin readLine function

Tags: kotlin, user-input

Whenever i try to execute a .jar file containing my code, it throws NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/io/ConsoleKt. So far i haven't found a solution to this problem but I think the problem has something to do with the `readLine()` function I have in the script but I don't know what. The weird thing is that my code ran perfectly in Intellij itself but once I built it started throwing this exception that never happened outside of IntelliJ. The specific error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/io/ConsoleKt
        at com.quantumzizo.calcualtorkotlin.DisplayKt.main(Display.kt:23)
        at com.quantumzizo.calcualtorkotlin.DisplayKt.main(Display.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.io.ConsoleKt
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 2 more
```

Is there solution that can solve this?

Comment: Have you bundled the Kotlin standard library into your `.jar` file?

Comment: I’ll try that now, i might not have

Comment: Somehow it seems that my Kotlin sdk is nonexistent in intellij. All there is in External libraris is my java sdk and a few gradle things.

Comment: Could you share the relevant parts of your `build.gradle(.kts)` you use for building the `.jar` file?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/DMSTPrGt That is the whole thing but it's pretty short

Comment: Thanks. :) Which Gradle task did you invoke to build the .jar? I think the default `jar` task doesn't include the dependencies, which includes the Kotlin standard library. That's why the class / file is missing in your .jar.

Comment: I just began kotlin and gradle, so I don't no which task I used actually. Intellij made the complicated parts of the build.gradle.kts for me

Comment: You could take a look at the Gradle plugin [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) which simplifies building a "fat jar", that's a .jar file that includes all required dependencies / libraries it needs to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out all I had to do was build a fat jar with all the dependencies. I used the Gradle plugin Shadow to make a fat jar.
Props to *@Endzeit* for suggesting that I use it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the solution is to bundle the Kotlin stdlib into the `.jar` file. `kotlin.io` is implicitly imported into the Kotlin code so the compilation finishes without errors, but at runtime `java` can't find the missing bytecode. Specifically the file `kotlin/io/ConsoleKt.class` holds the bytecode for the `readLine()` function.

I'd just like to extend the accepted answer for us who often directly invoke the Kotlin compiler. You need the `-include-runtime` option, so e.g.

`kotlinc -include-runtime -d kotlin_app.jar`

You can tell that the runtime is included if the file size of the jar (for a small program) is ~5MB, compared to ~1KB without the runtime.